# Apache default host

Tags: apache, web

I have Apache2, it's document root structure is:

```
/var/www/html
---index.html
---example.com
------/index.html
```

I want all requests to my-site.com to point to `example.com/index.html` and all other requests to be served `from /var/www/html`.

Here's my config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But all requests are served from Apache document root.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe Apache has notion of one document root, I could be wrong. If you want things for my-site.com to be served from its sub-directory than create an alias for mysite, so that http://localhost:80/mysite will give you contents of mysite, whereas http://localhost:80/ will pull from the "var/www/html" directory. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a NameVirtualHost directive somewhere in your config before the second virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Apache still serves ALL requests from /var/www/html

Comment: Fixed, thnx, need to put NameVirtualHost *:80 at the top of virtual host declarations.